# Check webkit version with javascript embedded pywebkitgtk?

Tags: javascript, webkit, gtk

Apparently the best way to check the version of webkit is

```
/AppleWebKit\/([\d.]+)/.exec(navigator.userAgent)
```

(as seen [here](https://gist.github.com/1081133) and a few other places). What is this /AppleWebKit/, a hidden variable, a constant, a regex?

I noticed it worked fine in the browser, but would not work in an embedded pywebkitgtk, it returns null. Is there something missing in the embedded webkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/AppleWebKit/([\d.]+)/ is a regular expression which navigator.userAgent is checked against.

The navigator object returns information about the browser you use (name, version, etc). So I guess this does not exist in pywebkitgtk, as it's only a framework for WebKitGtk, not a browser by itself.